# Google oauth2 failed for gapi.auth.authorize in windows phone and desktop IE metro browser

Tags: google-oauth

In the app I am using Google+ SignIn using oauth2. To authorize user, I am using gapi.auth.authorize(authParams) with javascript flow.

On g+ button click I am calling

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id:xyz, scope:'profile email', authuser:'', prompt:'select_account'})
```

NOTE:I am doing authuser:'', so that it will ask which account I want to getIn, instead of taking default account.

In browsers like chrome, safari, desktop IE and in devices like android, iphone it is working fine. But in windows phone and in IE Metro browser, on click its opening google's accountChooser page. On selecting the account, in callback I am getting error as on debug.

```
 Unhandled exception at line 13, column 32 in https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/3655170095-postmessagerelay.js 0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.
```

Couldn't get what is the issue? And how this can be handled?